# DIV tags get buggy when editing code

Tags: html, dreamweaver

Why does my DIV tags not work after editing pure text with DreamWeaver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You closed the `<footer>` element before the actual content.

```
<!-- content ends
================================================== --> 

<!-- footer starts
================================================== -->
<footer id="footer" class="clearfix">
  </footer> //This right here needs to go after your footer code.
    <div class="container"> 
    //... bla bla bla
    </div>
    <!--row ends--> 

  </div>

//Add this here: </footer>
//Don't forget to remove the other one up there.
<!-- footer ends
================================================== -->
```